# Access column after pandas groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some supermarket shopping trip data I want to analysis so I group the data by 4 attributes to be a primary key for a purchase session.

```
superMarketGrouped = superMarket.groupby(['Basket','Time','Date','Checkout'])
```

The result looks like this

[image]

I just want to extract the data in the Weekday column so get: Friday, Tuesday ... Saturday, Saturday. Into a data frame. I tried using superMarketGrouped['Weekday'] but that gets me additional data I don't need including basket, time, date and check out information. I have also seen other questions but they seem to be only solutions for when u want to obtain a column that was used to group.

This is example of the output when using superMarketGrouped['Weekday'] and advice from comments.

[image]

Comment: Those `Basket, Time, Date, Checkout` is the index. If you don't want them, do `superMarketGrouped['Weekday'].reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @QuangHoang, that seems like it could work but I am getting the following error:Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: I mean `superMarketGrouped['Weekday'].first().reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: grouped_df = df.groupby(col_names).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop = True))
grouped_df.droplevel(0)